# Converting strings to datetime in dataframe of one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that serves as an input to my calculations. The file contains a table that is read as a dataframe in my script. Two columns are datetime objects. When I am reading the file to a dataframe I am converting those values from default string type to datatime applying to_datetime function with UTC argument. The code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.read_csv('./Out/in.csv', index_col = 0, usecols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], header = 0)

df_in.iloc[:,2:4] = df_in.iloc[:,2:4].apply(pd.to_datetime, utc = True)

print(df_in)
```

Works like a charm on the following input CSV:

```
,Rig ID,Rig Name,Start Time,End Time
60,5,D004,2020-05-08 02:45:14.664341,2020-05-10 08:12:29.719839
70,5,D004,2020-05-14 07:59:09.280761,2020-05-15 02:11:52.358921
```

The moment the CSV file is reduced to 1 line, e.g.:

```
,Rig ID,Rig Name,Start Time,End Time
60,5,D004,2020-05-08 02:45:14.664341,2020-05-10 08:12:29.719839
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: data type not understood.
```

As far as I can understand it is something to do with slice assignment on single line dataframe

```
df_in.iloc[:,2:4] =
```

but I am struggling to find its cause and "smart" workaround.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: with `df_in.iloc[:,2:4]` you are selecting al lthe rows (with `:`) and columns 2 & 3 (with `,2:4`). This is irrespective of number of rows in the dataframe. So, i doubt this is the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that with older versions of pandas this can happen with when date fields are present in the data frame (specifically datetime64 variants).
So, instead of `iloc` try this...

```
df_in[['Start Time','End Time']] = df_in[['Start Time','End Time']].apply(pd.to_datetime, utc = True)
```